# Python script: Removing tabs, separating columns with comma, listing max/min

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a script in Python to remove tabs/blank spaces between two columns (one with x coordinates, the other with y coordinates) plus separate columns by a comma instead and list the maximum and minimum values of each column (2 values for each the x and y coordinates) at the end like this:

```
10000000    6000000
20000000    6100000
30000000    6200000
40000000    6300000
50000000    6400000
```

to appear like:

```
10000000,6000000
20000000,6100000
30000000,6200000
40000000,6300000
50000000,6400000

10000000 50000000 60000000 640000000
```

I'm a novice so any help wis v much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you want to write the minimum and maximum coordinates to an outputfile like that? Or did you just want to print them? Or did you just mean to read the input columns and use the values as integers in your program instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module for the output; simply loop over the input file and use `str.split()` to split lines into rows:

```
import csv

minimum = [float('inf'), float('inf')]
maximum = [float('-inf'), float('-inf')]

with open(inputfilename, 'r') as infile:
    with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for line in infile:
            row = map(int, line.split())
            minimum = map(min, zip(minimum, row))
            maximum = map(max, zip(maximum, row))
            writer.writerow(row)

x_extremes, y_extremes = zip(minimum, maximum)
print ' '.join(map(str, x_extremes)), ' '.join(map(str, y_extremes))
```

The `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` starter values make it easier to calculate the minimum and maximum coordinates later on.

The last line is

Comment: Hi Martijn. Thanks. I think I'm nearly there (I only changed int to float, as I'd forgotten to mention in my example that I am actually working with two decimal floats); however I'm getting an error saying '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'writewrow'?

Comment: Look closely at that exception, and compare that to my posted code. :-) (you are missing an `e` there).

Comment: Sorry about typo, was working on two terminals and did not copy paste it. Here it is: 
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'writerow'.
And in answer to your previous question, all I'm trying to do is to write the min-max coordinates to the output file together with the reformatted coordinates (i.e. no spaces, columns separated by comma).

Comment: @GeosDK: That's because I type these lines too often and replaced `csv.writer` for `csv.reader`... oops, corrected.

Comment: It works!! Thank you. My faith in humanity has been sligthly restored today.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
li = []
for line in lines:
    li.append(', '.join(line.split('\t')))

first_column = [int(x.split(',')[0]) for x in li]
second_column = [int(x.split(' ')[1]) for x in li]

for x in li:
    print (x)
print(min(first_column), max(first_column), min(second_column), max(second_column))
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur for being so quick. I'll check it out and let you know.